# HackerRank - Weather Observation Station 8

Tags: sql

I hope all is well.  Very basic SQL problem from HackerRank, but for some reason, the compiler will not accept my solution.  Here's what we have:

**The Problem:**

[image]

**My Solution**

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION 
WHERE CITY LIKE '[AEIOU]%[AEIOU]';
```

I've checked other posts regarding this very same problem, but none of the solutions presented seems to work in HackerRank.  Any insights is always most appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Query the list of CITY names from STATION which have vowels (i.e., a, e, i, o, and u) as both their first and last characters. Your result cannot contain duplicates.
i can use this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE (CITY LIKE 'a%' OR CITY LIKE 'e%' OR CITY LIKE 'i%' OR CITY LIKE 'o%' OR CITY LIKE 'u%') AND (CITY LIKE '%a' OR CITY LIKE '%e' OR CITY LIKE '%i' OR CITY LIKE '%o' OR CITY LIKE '%u');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are forgetting to use UPPER function with CITY column in WHERE condition -

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(UPPER(CITY), '^[AEIOU]+(.)+[AEIOU]$');
```

Comment: Just tried the UPPER function.  Still no good unfortunately.

Comment: Which DB are you using in Hackerrank? This works just perfectly fine for me in SQL Server

Comment: Initially DB2, then Oracle.  Also placed in commas:

SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION 
WHERE UPPER(CITY) LIKE '[A,E,I,O,U]%[A,E,I,O,U]';

Comment: @RashadNelson, Please try the edited query. This works perfectly for me in oracle.

Comment: No worries my friend.  I found another practice platform, sqlzoo.net.  I like this one much better.  No issues with the SQL good and it provides great feedback.  Thanks so much again for looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

SELECT DISTINCT (CITY)

FROM STATION

WHERE

LEFT(CITY,1) IN ('A','E','I','O','U')

AND

RIGHT(CITY,1) IN ('a','e','i','o','u');

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that solutions with `[]` didn't work with some database management systems in HackerRancks challenges, like MySQL, Oracle, and DB2. However it did work on MS SQL Server.

MS SQL Server code that worked for me

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY LIKE '[aeiou]%' AND CITY LIKE '%[aeiou]';
```

where I used `AND` operator to separate my conditions.

For the rest (DB2, MySQL, and Oracle) this (long) solution worked for me

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION
WHERE (CITY LIKE 'a%' OR CITY LIKE 'e%' OR CITY LIKE 'i%' OR CITY LIKE 'o%' OR CITY LIKE 'u%')
AND (CITY LIKE '%a' OR CITY LIKE '%e' OR CITY LIKE '%i' OR CITY LIKE '%o' OR CITY LIKE '%u');
```

where I used again `AND` to separate my two conditions.

Answer (score 0):

> ***this will work for mysql for sure***

`select distinct city from station where city regexp '^[aeiou]' and city regexp '[aeiou]$';`

Answer (score 0):

On MySql Server this works for me.

```
Select Distinct CITY From STATION Where CITY Like '[aeiou] % [aeiou]';
```

Answer (score 0):

Used this query.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE CITY REGEXP '^[aeiouAEIOU].*[aeiouAEIOU]$';
```

The REGEXP operator is used to match the CITY column against the regular expression pattern **'^[aeiouAEIOU].*[aeiouAEIOU]$'**. Here is an explanation of the pattern:

- **`^`** denotes the start of the string.
- `[aeiouAEIOU]` matches any single character that is one of the specified vowels (in both lowercase and uppercase).
- `*` matches zero or more of any character.
- `[aeiouAEIOU]$` matches any single character that is one of the specified vowels (in both lowercase and uppercase) at the end of the string.
- `$` denotes the end of the string.